# How to call Site with F# function?

Tags: iis, web, automation, f#-fake

I am new to F# and want to create IIS site with FAKE.

Now I see the code as the following.

[https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/develop/src/app/Fake.IIS/IISHelper.fs]

```
let Site (name : string) protocol binding (physicalPath : string) appPool (mgr : ServerManager) =
    let mutable site = mgr.Sites.[name] 
    match (site) with
    | null -> site <- mgr.Sites.Add(name, protocol, binding, physicalPath)
    | _ -> 
        SetPhysicalPath "/" physicalPath name (Some mgr)
        AddBindingToSite binding protocol name (Some mgr)

    site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName <- appPool
 site
```

How do I call this Site function to create site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realise this is a little late but the following will create a web site in IIS for you

```
open Fake
open Fake.IISHelper

(IIS
  (Site options.WebSiteName "http" (":9090:") @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot" "myAppPool")
  (ApplicationPool "myAppPool" true "v4.0")
  (Some(Application "/" )))
```

This method will create a website bound to Http on port 9090 located in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` additionally
it will create an application pool `myAppPool` and application and associated it with the site.